# Why cpython exposes 'PyTuple_SetItem' as C-API if tuple is immutable by design?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, ctypes, cpython

Tuple in [python](/questions/tagged/python) is immutable by design, so if we try to mutate a tuple object, [python](/questions/tagged/python) emits following `TypeError` which make sense.

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a[0] = 12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

So my question is, if tuple is immutable by design why ***cpython exposes `PyTuple_SetItem` as C-API***?.

From the documentation it's described as

> `int PyTuple_SetItem(PyObject *p, Py_ssize_t pos, PyObject *o)`
>
> Insert a reference to object `o` at position pos of the tuple pointed to
> by `p`. Return `0` on success. If pos is out of bounds, return `-1` and set
> an IndexError exception.

Isn't this statement exactly equal to `tuple[index] = value` in python layer?. If the goal was to create a tuple from collection of items we could have use [`PyTuple_Pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_Pack).

Additional note:

After lot of trial and error with `ctypes.pythonapi` I managed to mutate tuple object using `PyTuple_SetItem`

```
import ctypes

from ctypes import py_object

my_tuple = (1, 2, 3)
newObj = py_object(my_tuple)

m = "hello"

# I don't know why I need to Py_DecRef here. 
# Although to reproduce this in your system,  no of times you have 
# to do `Py_DecRef` depends on no of ref count of `newObj` in your system.
ctypes.pythonapi.Py_DecRef(newObj)
ctypes.pythonapi.Py_DecRef(newObj)
ctypes.pythonapi.Py_DecRef(newObj)

ctypes.pythonapi.Py_IncRef(m)



PyTuple_SetItem = ctypes.pythonapi.PyTuple_SetItem
PyTuple_SetItem.argtypes = ctypes.py_object, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.py_object

PyTuple_SetItem(newObj, 0, m)
print(my_tuple) # this will print `('hello', 2, 3)`
```

Comment: Related: [_Building self-referencing tuples_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61280229/674039)

Comment: `PyTuple_Pack` is only usable in cases where the number of tuple elements is fixed.  The only way to initialize a variable-sized tuple at the C level would be to call `PyTuple_SetItem` in a loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Similarly, there is a [`PyTuple_Resize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c._PyTuple_Resize) function with the warning

> Because tuples are supposed to be immutable, this should only be used
> if there is only one reference to the object. Do not use this if the
> tuple may already be known to some other part of the code. The tuple
> will always grow or shrink at the end. Think of this as destroying the
> old tuple and creating a new one, only more efficiently.

Looking at the source, there is a guard on the function

```
if (!PyTuple_Check(op) || Py_REFCNT(op) != 1) {
    .... error ....
```

Sure enough, this is only allowed when there is only 1 reference to the tuple - that reference being the thing that thinks its a good idea to change it. So, a tuple is "mostly immutable" but C code can change it in limited circumstances to avoid the penalty of creating a new tuple.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [note in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_SetItem) that say:

> Note This function “steals” a reference to o and discards a reference
> to an item already in the tuple at the affected position.

Otherwise in [Cpython Github docs](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0031e62973801d34a9e19ab7bb199e9668e32d7b/Doc/c-api/intro.rst#reference-count-details) we can see more details about this function and especially how and why this function `steals`the object reference. We can read:

> Incidentally, :c:func:`PyTuple_SetItem` is the only way to set tuple
> items; :c:func:`PySequence_SetItem` and :c:func:`PyObject_SetItem`
> refuse to do this since tuples are an immutable data type. You should
> only use :c:func:`PyTuple_SetItem` for tuples that you are creating
> yourself.
>
> Equivalent code for populating a list can be written using
> :c:func:`PyList_New` and :c:func:`PyList_SetItem`.
>
> However, in practice, you will rarely use these ways of creating and
> populating a tuple or list. There's a generic function,
> :c:func:`Py_BuildValue`, that can create most common objects from C
> values, directed by a :dfn:`format string`.